# How to give Apache permission to write and execute in /usr/local/<apps>

Tags: apache-2.2

I need some opinion here. What is the best method to give apache permission to create folder inside my /usr/local/ ?

Currently i'm doing apps that need the apache to create folder for each user inside it. But i dont think it possible, unless we create new group and change ownership and access to it. Is it right?

I need to know how it can be done.

Thanks